# Store unicode characters of string into attributedText of UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, string, unicode

I am trying to copy a NSMutableAttributedString(having unicode characters) into attributedText of UITextView. While doing that the unicode characters are saved separately as shown in the image:-

[image: log of attributed text of UITextView]

Here is the NSMutableAttributedString which should be saved in uitextview's attributed text:

[image: log of NSMutableAttributedString]

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: share some code .

Comment: These strings have different font therefore stored separately. I want to retrieve whole text not single character as it is stored

Comment: From where did you get the different logs? Why does it bother you that it added a font attribute to manage the different characters? It maybe be due to the fact that San Francisco Font can't render theses characters itself, and ask then KohinoorDevanagari to do it or it will be unreadable characters.

Comment: I want this separated string to act as a single text so that I can delete it all at once..